# When number is given get correspondent month in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to get the month when given the correspondent number

Ex:

```
01 - January
02 - February
03 - March
.
.
.
12 -  December
```

How can I do this with variable and mapping in XSLT. I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: What version of XSLT does your processor support?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I am using XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$month=1">January</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month=2">February</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month=3">March</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month=4">April</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month=5">May</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month=6">June</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month=7">July</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month=8">August</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month=9">September</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month=10">October</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month=11">November</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month=12">December</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

---

In XSLT 2.0 you can do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-date(xs:date(concat('0001-', $month, '-01')), '[MNn]')"/>
```

(this is assuming your `$month` variable is already zero-padded to two digits).