# Date format transform in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to transform XML value to date format.

Input:

```
<pub-date type="date">
    <day>14</day>
    <month>02</month>
    <year>2019</year>
</pub-date>
```

The output should be:

```
<dateformat name="Date" value="February 14, 2019"/>
```

Tried code :

```
<xsl:template name="insert-date">
    <dateformat name="Date">
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="descendant::pub-date[@type='date']/concat(month,' ',day,', ',year)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </tps:fieldSet>
</xsl:template>
```

But I am getting month as `02`. I want to transform it into `February`. How can I change my code to get the desired output.

Comment: The answer depends on what version of XS:LT your processor supports - cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57145609/when-number-is-given-get-correspondent-month-in-xslt/57145944#57145944

Comment: @michael.hor257k XSLT 2.0 is the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN XSLT 2.0, you could do a one liner:

```
<dateformat name="Date" value="{format-date(xs:date(concat(year, '-', month, '-', day)), '[MNn] [D], [Y]')}"/>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1yac

---

Note that this assumes that both your `day` and `month` are zero-padded to 2 digits.